# Why does this Fibonacci code only allow 8 sequences?

Tags: c

I just coded the Fibonacci sequence and this code has a limitation that I can't enter more than 8 sequences. How can I debug this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Fibonacci(int N);

int main(){
    int N;
    printf("Enter the max term of Fibonacci sequence : ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    Fibonacci(N);
}
void Fibonacci(int N){
    int fib0=0, fib1=1, fib;
    printf("%d", fib1);
    while(fib<=N){
        fib=fib0+fib1;
        fib0=fib1;
        fib1=fib;
        printf("\t%d",fib1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you enter more?

Comment: @M.Kotzjan his `while` loop is incorrect.

Comment: Alfad, Hint: what is the value of `fib` the first time `while(fib<=N){` is executed?

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect loop in your code. Just replace:

```
while(fib<=N)
```

with:

```
for (int i=0; i< N; i++)
```

and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should not iterate up to N rather you should iterate up to N-th Sequence

Following code will work as you expected:

```
    void Fibonacci(int N){
      int fib0=0, fib1=1, fib;
      printf("%d", fib1);
      int sequence = 0;
      while(sequence ++ <=N){
         fib=fib0+fib1;
         fib0=fib1;
         fib1=fib;
         printf("\t%d",fib1);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
int main() {

  int i, n;

  // initialize first and second terms
  int t1 = 0, t2 = 1;

  // initialize the next term (3rd term)
  int nextTerm = t1 + t2;

  // get no. of terms from user
  printf("Enter the number of terms: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  // print the first two terms t1 and t2
  printf("Fibonacci Series: %d, %d, ", t1, t2);

  // print 3rd to nth terms
  for (i = 3; i <= n; ++i) {
    printf("%d, ", nextTerm);
    t1 = t2;
    t2 = nextTerm;
    nextTerm = t1 + t2;
  }

  return 0;
}
```